# Servlet Annotation Into xml

Tags: java, servlets

my servlet annotation:

```
@MultipartConfig(
    location = "\\tmp\\bonita\\",
    fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*100,
    maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)
```

i want to remove it from the java code and put it in a web.xml on the apache tomcat but got no idea of the proper syntax, I already got those lines into the xml file:

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>QddFileUpload</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.example.QddFileUpload</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can do like this**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>QddFileUpload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.QddFileUpload</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>104448</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>26214400</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>QddFileUpload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```